# Dynamically create variables in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dynamic

I have been trying to figure this out for some time now and can't seem to figure out an answer to it. I don't see why this would be impossible. I am coding in VB.NET.

**Here is my problem:**
I need to dynamically create variables and be able to reference them later on in the code.

**More Details:**
The number of variables comes from some math run against user defined values. In this specific case I would like to just create integers, although I foresee down the road needing to be able to do this with any type of variable. It seems that my biggest problem is being able to name them in a unique way so that I would be able to reference them later on.

**Simple Example:**
Let's say I have a value of 10, of which I need to make variables for. I would like to run a loop to create these 10 integers. Later on in the code I will be referencing these 10 integers.

It seems simple to me, and yet I can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best way to do something like this is with the `Dictionary(T)` class.  It is generic, so you can use it to store any type of objects.  It allows you to easily store and retrieve code/value pairs.  In your case, the "key" would be the variable name and the "value" would be the variable value.  So for instance:

```
Dim variables As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
variables("MyDynamicVariable") = 10  ' Set the value of the "variable"
Dim value As Integer = variables("MyDynamicVariable")  ' Retrieve the value of the variable
```

Comment: This is the closest you're likely to get but you'll need a dictionary for each data type

Comment: @Basic Yes, you would, unless you want to forgo the type-checking and just make it a `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` in which case the value could be any type of object.

Comment: This looks like it will do the trick. I've never used the Dictionary(T) class until this. Thanks for the quick answer and the commented code snippet.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Don't even suggest it ;) May as well turn off strict mode too... *shudder* Also, can you imagine how messy it would get with all those `CInt`, `CDbl`, etc to actually use it?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a `List`

```
Dim Numbers As New List(Of Integer)

For i As Integer = 0 To 9 
    Numbers.Add(0)
Next
```

The idea of creating a bunch of named variables on the fly is not something you are likely to see in any VB.Net program. If you have multiple items, you just store them in a list, array, or some other type of collection.

Answer (score 0):

'Dim an Array
Dim xCount as Integer
Dim myVar(xCount) as String

AddButton Event . . .
xCount += 1
myVar(xCount) = "String Value"

'You will have to keep Track of what xCount Value is equal to to use.
'Typically could be an ID in A DataTable, with a string Meaning