# How to declare a variable using a different variable

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to be able to allow the user to input a string and then use that string to create a different variable. For example:

```
Dim UserInput As String
UserInput = Console.Readline()
Dim (UserInput) As String
```

So if the user input "Hello" a new variable called 'Hello' would be made.

Is this possible and if not, are there any alternatives?

Comment: Why would you do such a thing?  Why would the user need to know the name of a variable?  What you're suggesting is ludicrous.  What is the end game here, so that we can suggest a better way to achieve it?

Comment: The names of variables **must be known at compile-time**. What you're asking for here is to wait until run-time to know the name. That just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of variables **must be known at compile-time**. What you're asking for here is to wait until run-time to know the name. That just doesn't work

What you can do is use a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` to hold your data.

This code works:

```
Dim UserInput As String
UserInput = Console.Readline()
Dim UserInputData As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
UserInputData(UserInput) = "Some Value"
Console.WriteLine(UserInputData(UserInput))
```

So if you enter `Bar` then the dictionary has this value in it:

[image: Dictionary]

The bottom-line is that everything is known at compile-time, but you can store data based on the user input at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to dynamically create single variables in VB.net. However, you can use lists or dictionaries (source: [Dynamically create variables in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726809/dynamically-create-variables-in-vb-net))

Answer (score 0):

The name of the variable does not matter to the user because they will never see it. They will only ever see the data it holds. There really is no reason for this